# How much disk space do I have?

Tags: linux, disk-space, df

I'm trying to find out how much disk space a system has, but df does not show the / filesystem :

```
# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on                                                                      
devtmpfs                212820         0    212820   0% /dev
none                    216832         4    216828   0% /dev/shm
mtd1                      1536       476      1060  31% /flash
tmpfs                    10240         0     10240   0% /queues
#
```

Where is my /, and how much space is on it?

Comment: Try `df -k`. Should show you `/`

Comment: What is the output of `df /`?  Also, please post the contents of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @Insane the `-k` option is (on Debian at least) an alias for `--block-size=1K`, why would that show extra filesystems? I would be more interested in `df -a` output. Also, even more interesting, the output of `mount` without any parameters.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I've only ever used it with the `-k` flag and it's only ever shown all my file systems, so I commented with the suggestion.

Comment: @Insane I've never used the `-k` flag and it's only ever shown all my filesystems hehe. I don't see anything different in the output either as the block size is 1K by default I think. `-a` stands for `include dummy filesystems` which also (quite useless) shows mounts like `/proc`.

Comment: I would probably look at a partitioning tool like gparted or fdisk to answer this question. it avoids all the mount points, and just shows you disks and volumes.

Comment: @FrankThomas but the mount points are the interesting part? How has he even booted to the current point without having `/` mounted? Where is `/bin/df` even loaded from in this command? I've never seen `df` *not* output the root filesystem. And `mount` without parameters will (probably) show the mount flags used which might explain things.

Comment: As described [here](http://strugglers.net/~andy/blog/2009/11/26/my-root-file-system-doesnt-show-up-in-df-anymore/) then the UUID in `/etc/fstab` can be incorrect and a mismatch with the bootloader UUID occurs. When that happens then utils like `df` and `mount` can't find the corresponding partition and so do not publish it.

Comment: Thanks guys, but in truth I need to be able to parse the values in a script, and the unit has no GUI. So ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Disk Usage Analyzer](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/)** utility to see free space and space used by system and other applications.

[image]